# complement of a graph is non planar

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove that the complement of $C_n$ is non planar for every $n\geq7$. I only know the definition of non planar.
Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part is doing it for $\overline{C_7}$. Writing $1...7$ for the vertices of $C_7$, the complement contains the edges $13,35,57,72,24,46,61$, which form a cycle. So any drawing must contain this cycle.[image]

Now look at the other edges, and try to determine whether they go inside or outside the cycle. You'll find once you make the choice for one edge, that determines two others, and eventually leads to a contradiction.

Finally, if $n>7$ then $\overline{C_n}$ contains $\overline{C_7}$ as a subgraph, so if it is non-planar for $n=7$ it is non-planar for all $n\geq 7$.